# Form won't submit with custom validation error message

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to create a custom validation error message. When I try to submit my form , without filling the input box I get the custom error message. However, even when I fill up the input box the form does not submit I get my custom validtion error message.

```
<input name="trailerNumber" class="form-control" type="text"  aria-describedby="enter Part Number" placeholder="Trailer Number" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Trailer Number must be filled to initiate order')"
   onvalid="this.setCustomValidity('')">
```

Is there a way to set custom validatoin on required field?

Comment: Please add all the relevant code including the form tags and the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `onvalid` event listener, try the `oninput` or `onchange` events to reset the custom validity.

According to MDN, there is no `onvalid` event handler.

```html
<form action="" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); alert('Submitted')" method="GET">
  <input
    name="trailerNumber"
    required="required"
    minlength="5"
    placeholder="Trailer Number"
    oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Trailer Number must be filled to initiate order')"
   oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"
 >
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```